# How to Download Facebook Look back Video?

Tags: facebook, video

What should Do, If I want to download [Facebook Lookback Video](https://www.facebook.com/lookback/)

Comment: Now you Can use IDM also too download the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reference](http://gist.github.com/akshatmittal/8802537)

Simple JS Script to get Video URL from Facebook's Look Back

Copy paste this whole code into Chrome Console and press enter.
You can execure this script on any page on Facebook.
It will give you the video URL, open it, view it, download it, do whatever you want to. :P

The video URL will popup in front of you, press Ctrl + C to copy it.

To do so, open Chrome Console, Ctrl + Shift + J, "Console" tab.
Copy paste the whole thing there.

To share it, just open the link and download it by pressing Ctrl + S.
Upload it to YouTube or wherever you want to. Share, enjoy! :)

Keep Sharing this with everyone! :)

```
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            ss = xmlhttp.responseText.split('[["params","')[1].split('"],["width","960"]')[0];
            var x = ss;
            var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
            x = x.replace(r, function (match, grp) {return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); });
            x = unescape(x);
            console.log(JSON.parse(x).video_data[0].hd_src);
            prompt("Here's your video URL (HD)! Press Ctrl + C to copy it!", JSON.parse(x).video_data[0].hd_src)
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/lookback", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Oh wow! I never expected someone to use my code as an answer on SO! :D

http://gist.github.com/akshatmittal/8802537

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the SD and HD sources directly from the flashvars of the embed used to display the video. In Google Chrome inspect the page for the "content" div you'll find a div with class "swfObject".

Decoding the flasvar, you'll get something similar to:

```
params={ 

    "autoplay":true, 
    "autorewind":true, 
    "default_hd":false, 
    "dtsg":"AQAAJp6S", 
    "inline_player":false, 
    "lsd":null, 
    "min_progress_update":300, 
    "pixel_ratio":1, 
    "preload":false, 
    "source":"lookback", 
    "start_index":0,
    "start_muted":false,
    "use_spotlight":false,
    "video_data":[

    {
        "hd_src":"https:\/\/lookbackvideo7-a.akamaihd.net\/hvideo-ak-ash2\/v\/t55\/1774977_10104243234253383320144_17978_n.mp4?oh=7d70ce01b4c6dff2345d48e6e938a9df65f&oe=52F59B08&__gda__=1391855368_9ae234b1cce92effd53d05cdfb6e884f323",

        "is_hds":false,"index":0,"rotation":0,

        "sd_src":"https:\/\/lookbackvideo7-a.akamaihd.net\/hvideo-ak-ash2\/v\/t54\/1785524_101045234234383320144_19170_n.mp4?oh=1116ee0f06e59c4180648234bac62a148ea&oe=52F5A983&__gda__=1391848771_03b13324ffa3791cc64e0d070465107c7c8",

        "thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net\/hvthumb-ak-prn1\/t15\/1542287_101045533833922349984_10104553383320144_60544_503_b.jpg",

        "thumbnail_height":540,"thumbnail_width":960,
        "video_duration":62,
        "video_id":"101045523423383320144"
    }]}
```

The two important values here are hd_src and sd_src (i've garbled mine for security purposes):

```
"hd_src":"https:\/\/lookbackvideo7-a.akamaihd.net\/hvideo-ak-ash2\/v\/t55\/1774977_10104553382342320144_17978_n.mp4?oh=7d70ce01b4c6dff5d48e6e938234a9df65f&oe=52F59B08&__gda__=1391855368234_9aeb1cce92effd53d05cdfb6e884f323",

"sd_src":"https:\/\/lookbackvideo7-a.akamaihd.net\/hvideo-ak-ash2\/v\/t54\/1785524_101045532342343320144_19170_n.mp4?oh=1116ee0f06e59c4180623424448bac62a148ea&oe=52F5A983&__gda__=139184232428771_03b13ffa3791cc64e0d070465107c7c8",
```

Load your desired quality (High Definition or Standard Definition) URL into a new browser window, right click on the video and "Save Video As."

Answer (score -2):

[www.fundawn.com](http://www.fundawn.com) is the best web place where people can download and watch public videos and photos of top facebook celebrities and others,  all in one place.

Just check it.

[image]